# Meaning of "plus" ($+$) index

Tags: notation, index-notation

So I came across a notation I can't remember seeing, or at least not in such context. I have looked around and asked a few people unsuccessfully. It is from https://arxiv.org/pdf/1805.11572.pdf and the line, or at least the part of the line that I don't know about
$$
\lambda\cdot\mathbb{E} \left[ (||\nabla_x\Psi_\Theta(X)||-1)^2_+\right],
$$
where I don't know what the $+$ index would refer to. Would somebody have seen that notation?

Comment: It can mean many things, one notation is $(x)_+ = \max(0,x)$.

Comment: It may be worth to say that this appears in formula $(6)$ and in Algorithm $1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @copper.hat notes, a common notation is$$(x)_+:=\max\{0,\,x\}=\frac{x+|x|}{2},\,(x)_-:=\min\{0,\,x\}=\frac{x-|x|}{2}.$$The corollaries$$(x)_++(x)_-=x,\,(x)_+-(x)_-=|x|$$motivates this notation. Further, $(x)_+$ is common in machine learning as a [rectifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rectifier_(neural_networks)).

Comment: Yes I do remember this one. Should have thought further, did not consider it since the square would bring it back to positive. But if you don't want the value to be negative at first, then you take it to be zero. Thanks!